# Can I have the \overfullrule rule colored in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking, color, warnings, rules

I know that I can use `\overfullrule=5pt` to get overfull lines marked with a black marker. I am using pdfLaTeX. Is there a way I can get this marker or something similar in magenta instead?

Comment: The macro `\overfullrule=5pt` only determines the *width* of the "slug," i.e., of the marker that's placed to the right of the text in overfull lines. I couldn't find a detailed-enough explanation in either "TeX by Topic" or in "TeX for the inpatient" to determine how and were TeX creates the slug. I hope somebody else can help you out.

Comment: The slug is inserted down in TeX's bowels, if `\overfullrule` is positive *and* an `\hbox` is overfull. Usually this happens during paragraphing, but not necessarily. I believe there's no way to set the color.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Aditya gave a very nice, portable solution (Patrick's is very nice, too, but less portable).

I've made a little package called `overcolored` out of it, which can currently be found [on github](https://github.com/raphink/overcolored):

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex,paper=10cm:10cm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[color=blue,
            width=3pt,
            height=0.5\baselineskip]{overcolored}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
I've seen quite a few shortcomings in complex environments using Aditya's code, while Patrick's code has no side effects that I could see. For this reason, the package now supports both implementations. When compiled with LuaTeX, it will use Patrick's code, otherwise, Aditya's code is used.

I still have to adapt the options to work with Patrick's code. Supporting the `width` parameter was quite straightforward, the height is a bit more tricky, and supporting color names with PDF annotations seems much more tricky still...

Comment: I tried this package on the book but keep getting the following error on figures:
`! Incompatible list can't be unboxed.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.788 \end{figure}`
I will try to come up with a minimal example and file as an issue on Github.

Comment: @jonalv: using PDFTeX I guess? You didn't try the LuaTeX implementation?

Comment: Okey further studies has made me see "quite a few shortcomings in complex environments" as well. I suppose that one can't have everything...

Comment: yea, actually I am gonna start looking for a LuaTex for dummies or something real-soon-now™ :)

Comment: @jonalv: On the other hand, the LuaTeX implementation works great for me. All it requires is to use another rendering engine with the same package.

Answer (score 30):

I am not sure if this is possible with old fashioned TeX/pdfTeX, but it is with LuaTeX (of course, it is!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase,luacode}
\overfullrule 5pt
\begin{luacode}

local VLIST = node.id("vlist")
local HLIST = node.id("hlist")
local GLUE = node.id("glue")
local RULE = node.id("rule")

magentabox = function(head)
  while head do
    if head.id == VLIST or head.id == HLIST then
      -- go through the hlists (the rows)
      magentabox(head.head)

    -- if there's a rule after the rightskip, this is the overfull box
    -- node id 10 == glue, glue subtype 9 is rightskip, node id 2 is a rule

    elseif head.id == GLUE and head.subtype == 9 and head.next and head.next.id == RULE then
       -- this must be an overfull box
       local w1, w2
       w1 = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
       w1.data = "q 1 0 1 rg"
       w1.mode = 1
       w2 = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
       w2.data = " Q"
       w2.mode = 1

       w1.next = head.next -- the rule
       head.next = w1      -- color start
       w1.next.next = w2   -- color end

       node.slide(head)    -- adjust prev pointers
    end
    head = head.next
  end
  return true
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",magentabox,"magentabox")

\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\hsize 1.7in A verylongword verylongword verylongword
\end{document}
```

[image: magenta overfull box]

Comment: Very nice. Yet a reason in the pile for switching to LuaTeX. I am afraid the pile is not big enough to warrant converting a 500 pages book project though. After all this is just a draft mode feature. I really would need it in pdfTeX for this project...

Comment: @jonalv: LuaTeX is based on PDFTeX and largely compatible with pretty much everything PDFTeX. The question might be what is *keeping* you from switching, still? Have you tried processing your 500 pages book through `lualatex`, just to check?

Comment: @Patrick: this solution does color overfull boxes, but it also ruins the next lines. It seems to generate a negative increasing indentation for every line.

Comment: @Raphink: I have edited my solution (`mode=1` for `w1` and `w2`). This will change the positioning of the PDF instructions (`pdf_literal`). I still don't have a good feeling when other modes then 0 are necessary.

Comment: That works @Patrick, thanks. Going to make an `overcolored` package (unless someone finds a nicer name) :-)

Comment: @Raphink: Touché I guess. Honestly I have only tried XeLaTeX except for PDFTeX so far but I did have some trouble with that and I was under the impression that lualatex was newer and hence an even less mature project thus giving me (and all the not so computer savvy authors (some of which I am very happy are writing tex at all in the first place) potential headache with all the various packages currently being employed in that patch-work... So, I am not sure I dare, but no I haven't tried. :)
I probably will dare to one day.

Comment: @jonalv: While XeTeX was written from scratch (imo), LuaTeX is based on PDFTeX, and matured quite fast. It's currently a bêta (version 0.70 in TeXLive 2011) but is already stable enough to be used. That said, Aditya provided a more portable solution (which I have since packaged).

Comment: @cjorssen thanks for the »bug report«, I'll fix it.

Comment: @cjorssen I have edited the code, but it worked for me with TeXlive 2016

Answer (score 25):

Copied from a [TeX pearl](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91pearls.pdf) by Paweł Jackowski. In his words, **never underestimate TeX's bells and whistles**.

```
\def\ooops{\hbox to\wd0{\setbox0=\hbox to\wd0{\unhbox0}%
    \unhbox0 \ifnum\badness>10000 \rlap{\tiny\quad Ooops!}\fi}}

\interlinepenalty=-50000 % force the break between each two lines
\maxdeadcycles=50        % allow upto 50 \outputs with no \shipout
\newtoks\orioutput \orioutput=\output % wrap the original \output routine
\output
    {\ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \the\orioutput
     \else \ifnum\outputpenalty<-\maxdimen \the\orioutput
     \else
     \unvbox255        % flush the entire list back
     \setbox0=\lastbox % strip the very last box
     \nointerlineskip  % avoid doubled interline glue
     \ooops            % make the test and return the box back.
     \advance\outputpenalty by50000
     \penalty\outputpenalty % weak lie that nothing happened...
     \fi\fi}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=1.5in,a6paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

This completely useless example shows a not-so-useless trick, which might be
used for quite advanced applications, such as line-numbering, some kind of
paragraph decoration, page optimization and probably many others. Things become
much more complicated if math displays, \verb|\marks|, \verb|\inserts| or
\verb|\vadjusts| come into play, but they don-F¢t spoil all of the game.
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

The definition of `ooops` can be changed to give a colored rule instead of the text. For example (thanks to Jake)

```
\def\ooops{\hbox to\wd0{\setbox0=\hbox to\wd0{\unhbox0}%
    \unhbox0 \ifnum\badness>10000 \rlap{\color{magenta}{\rule{0.5em}{3ex}}}\fi}}
```

and loading `xcolor`.

Comment: Replacing `Oooops!` with `\color{magenta}{\rule{0.5em}{3ex}}` and loading the `xcolor` package is one way to get colored rules.

Comment: Very nice! It doesn't work for every slug (an oversized paragraph cell in an alignment, for example), but does the main job.

Comment: @Aditya: Nice, but you need `\usepackage{xcolor}`. Also, the rules break the interline.

Comment: @Raphink: Perhaps wrapping the rules around `\smash` will help.

Comment: @Aditya: `\smash` works well :-)

Comment: @Aditya: do you mind if I make a package from your code?

Comment: Its not my code...but I am sure that Jacko won't mind either.

Comment: Not that I really understand what it does either, but it would be nice for people to do that easily :-)

Comment: For some reason, this seems to fail with `multicols`.

Comment: @Raphink: Well...`multicols` also changes the output routine, so it is not surprising that the above code will fail with that. One option could be to add this code **after** loading multicols.

Comment: @Aditya: `imakeidx` is loading `multicols` for the index, so I don't know how I could do that.

Comment: You can restore the original output routine before the index: `\let\output=\orioutput`

Comment: Actually, when running on a large book, this broke the page breaks and added line numbers everywhere...

Answer (score 7):

Much has happened since topskip gave a LuaTeX solution. Relevant to us is the new callback `hpack_quality`. Just turn off the `\overfullrule` and replace topskip's luatex block with the following, adapting `b.width` and the colour in `a.data` to taste. Also, if you prefer overfullrules of fixed height and width, just assign those to `b.height` and `b.depth`:

```
\begin{luacode}
  ofbox = function(incident, detail, head, first, last)
    if incident == "overfull" then
      local a, b, c
      b = node.new("rule",0)
      b.width = tex.sp("1mm")
      a = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
      a.data = "q 1 0 1 rg"
      a.mode = 1
      c = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
      c.data = " Q"
      c.mode = 1
      a.next = b
      b.next = c
      node.slide(a)
      return a
    end
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_quality",ofbox,"ofbox")
\end{luacode}
```

This has the added benefit of working with overfull display math as well.

Comment: This is my very first attempt at writing lua code. Many thanks to @topskip for giving me the idea, and some code to look at!

Comment: Added bonus: The code is easily adapted to make underfullrules as well! (With a different colour, of course.)

Comment: Nice use case for the `hpack_quality` callback!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen that's amazing, thanks so much! However, its seems to remove the warning about overfull boxes from log (at least the one I see in texstudio). Is that intended? Can that be restored?

Comment: @bonanza You'll have to write your own warning. I have been using this code: `texio.write_nl("### overfull: " .. string.format("%.2f",detail/186467) .. "mm at line " .. first .. "-"  .. last)` followed by another `texio.write_nl("")` inside the `if` block. The `detail` variable measures the overfullness in scaled points `sp`. I chose to convert it to millimeters; you may prefer points.