# post_linebreak_filter and glyph analysis

Tags: luatex, lua

When calling a function with a `post_linebreak_filter` callback, the nodelist  only contains nodes of type 0 (hlist), 10 (glue) and 12 (penalty), whereas when using a `pre_linebreak_filter` callback, type 37 (glyph) nodes are also sent.

Is there a way to analyze glyph nodes of a paragraph after the paragraph has been rendered (in order to insert PDF annotations)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really the whole story. See the [LuaTeX wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX#And_what_about_real_content.3F) and there you'll see that the boxes 0 (hlists) that you find are in fact the lines and these lines contain the glyphs. So what you have to do is: if you find a hlist (id 0), go through the node list where the entry "head" points to. See my answer to [the overfull rule question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28294/can-i-have-the-overfullrule-rule-colored-in-pdflatex/28299#28299) where I call `magentabox` again with `head.head`. And for analyzing the nodelist: to get a graphical representation to use with graphviz (gv) see [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/556247).