# Is it possible to make LaTeX mark overfull boxes in the output?

Tags: warnings

Is it possible to make LaTeX mark overfull boxes in the output, for example by drawing red rectangles in the PDF where the boxes overflow? The purpose -- to more easily "see" where the problems are in the output.

Comment: `\documentclass[draft]{article}`

Comment: This is the duty of the `draft` option to `\documentclass`

Comment: Out of curiosity: are there other visual warnings available?

Comment: @ChristianLindig unfortunately, not really. You cannot visualize `underfull \hbox`, nor `over/underfull \vbox` nor `over/underfull \vbox while \output is active`. You have to read the `.log` to find these.

Comment: @ChristianLindig: Unrelated to overfull boxes, there are packages that provide visual debugging/warnings. Some are even colored :-)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As David Carlisle and egreg said, you can use the `draft` option in most classes.

If you wish to do it by hand (for example, you need a `final` option to check for another package's rendering) or tune it, you can use

```
\overfullrule=1mm
```

in the document preamble.

Comment: You're my hero. :-) Microtype was turning off its stuff because of `[draft]`, which apparently can have significant effects on the output.

Comment: Seems like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28294/412 provides a way to color the marker.

Comment: @EvanED Just for the sake of completeness, you can pass the `final` option to the `microtype` package to make it do its thing even in draft mode. I always do this because frankly the whole display overfull boxes thing is completely useless if it doesn't respect `microtype`'s changes.

Comment: I would suggest using \overfullrule=5mm, so it shows up in the PDF page thumbprints in the side panel.