# Is there a way to highlight overfull hboxes?

Tags: overflow

I want to visually find the overfull hboxes in my document. Is there a way to highlight them in the document?

Comment: use the `draft` mode?

Comment: `
\documentclass[draft]{book}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make LaTeX mark overfull boxes in the output?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75140/is-it-possible-to-make-latex-mark-overfull-boxes-in-the-output)